# Knockout JS shopping cart exercise

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

I am learning knockout js and have begun building a simple shopping cart.

This shopping cart basically ask the user to select a category from a dropdownlist and then a second dropdownlist is then populated with products.

When the user selected a product, the product information is displayed i.e. name/price/qty/total. An 'add Item' button is also visible.

the qty data is a textbook where the user can increment the value. If the user increments the qty value the total value will calculate the new total i.e. (price * qty).

When the user clicks the add item button the product id, name, qty and total are stored and displayed (except id) in an adjacent div i.e. cart list.

The problem i am having is that when an item is in the shopping cart with qty 1 and i want to add a new item to the cart with a qty of 2. The qty value in the cart is also changing to 2. The values should stay at 1 also the total value in the shopping cart is matching that of the new item.

here is the code:

```
<div id="exp2">
    <div>
        <span>
            <select id="ddlCat" data-bind="options: lstCategories, optionsText: 'name',
            optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Select Category...',
            value: selectedCate"></select>
        </span>
        <span data-bind="visible: lstProducts().length > 0">
            <select id="ddlProd" data-bind="options: lstProducts, optionsText: 'name',
            optionsValue: 'id',  optionsCaption: 'Select Product...',
            value: selectedProdId"></select>
        </span>
        <span data-bind="with: selectedProd()">
            Price: £<span id="pPrice" data-bind="text: price"></span>, &nbsp;
            Qty <input type="text" id="pQty" data-bind="value: quantity" style="width:30px;"
                       placeholder="" required />
            SubTotal: £<span data-bind="text: itemTotal()"></span>
            <span><button id="btnAdd" class="btnAdd" data-bind="click: addItem">Add to cart</button></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Items In Cart</h3>
        <ul id="lstCart" data-bind="foreach: cart">
            <li>
                Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span>&nbsp;
                Qty: <span data-bind="text: qty"></span>&nbsp;
                Item Total: £<span data-bind="text: itemTotal"></span>&nbsp;
            </li>
        </ul>
        Sub Total: £<span data-bind="text: subTotal()"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
        var categories = [];
        var products = [];
        var cartLines = [];

        $.ajax({
            url: '../KnockoutTut/page5GetCat',
            type: "GET", cache: false, async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                //alert('Process Successful');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var id = data[i].id; var name = data[i].name;
                    //var nCat = new Category(id, name);
                    categories.push( new Category(id,name));
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert("Error")
                alert(jqXHR.status + "," + jqXHR.responseText + "," + errorThrown);
            }
        });

        function getProd(catId) {
            products = [];
            var value = { 'value': catId };
            var json = JSON.stringify(value);
            $.ajax({
                url: '../KnockoutTut/page5GetProd',
                type: "POST", data: json, cache: false, async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json", traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert('Process Successful');
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var id = data[i].id; var name = data[i].name;
                        var price = data[i].price; var qty = data[i].qty;
                        products.push(new Product(id, name, price, 1));
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //alert("Error")
                    alert(jqXHR.status + "," + jqXHR.responseText + "," + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        function Category(id, name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        };

        function Item(id, name, qty, itemTotal) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.qty = qty;
            this.itemTotal = itemTotal;
        };

        function Product(id, name, price, qty) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.qty = qty;
        };

        function viewModel() {

            var self = this;
            self.lstCategories = ko.observableArray(categories);
            self.lstProducts = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.cart = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.selectedCate = ko.observable();
            self.selectedProdId = ko.observable();
            self.selectedProd = ko.observable();
            self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
            self.catQty = ko.observable();

            self.itemTotal = ko.pureComputed(function () {
                return self.selectedProd() ? self.selectedProd().price * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0;
            });

            self.subTotal = ko.pureComputed(function () {
                var total = 0;
                $.each(self.cart(), function () { total += this.itemTotal() })
                return total;
            });

            self.selectedCate.subscribe(function (pCatId) {
                var catId = pCatId;
                if ($.isNumeric(catId)) {
                    getProd(catId);
                }
                self.lstProducts(products);
            });

            self.selectedProdId.subscribe(function (pProdId) {
                var pId = pProdId;
                var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(lstProducts(), function (item) {
                    return pId === item.id;
                });
                self.selectedProd(match);
                //alert(selectedProd().qty);
            });

            self.addItem = function (item) {
                var nId = item.id; var nName = item.name; var cartQty = quantity; var iTot = itemTotal;
                cart.push(new Item(nId, nName, cartQty, iTot));
                //cart.push(cartLines);
            };                
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("exp2"));
```

Remember i am new to knockout js. so please excuse the bad coding. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues seems to be with what value are you using for showing the data after an item has been added. If I am not wrong, you are assigning observable to the property `cartQty` inside of the `cart` array. Since, you are using the added values in `cart` just to show as label information and user is not supposed to change that (unless of course after deleting that record and then adding a new one after the desired modifications), there is no need to use two way binding and hence no need to assign observable like you are doing here -

```
var cartQty = quantity;
```

So, it is always better to separate these by assigning only the value enclosed by the observable, rather than the observable itself.

You can try something like this -

```
var cartQty = quantity();
```

So that changing the quantity does not have its side effects elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked. I changed the cartQty = quantity to cartQty = quantity(). In order for me to understand better. If i do an assignment like var a = b ( b is an observable), a is basically a duplicate of b i.e. a is now also an observable. Whereas if i did a = b(), a is referencing the value contained within b.

Comment: bingo! you got it :) please accept this as an answer so that it may be helpful for others in future..